# Meaning of Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Our teacher gave us the following definition of **Big O notation**:

```
O(f(n)): A function g(n) is in O(f(n)) (“big O of f(n)”) if there exist
constants c > 0 and N such that |g(n)| ≤ c |f(n)| for all n > N.
```

I'm trying to tease apart the various components of this definition. First of all, I'm confused by what it means for g(n) to be *in* O(f(n)). What does *in* mean?

Next, I'm confused by the overall second portion of the statement. Why does saying that the absolute value of g(n) less than or equal f(n) for all n > N mean anything about **Big O Notation**?

My general intuition for what **Big O Notation** means is that it is a way to describe the runtime of an algorithm. For example, if bubble sort runs in O(n^2) in the worst case, this means that it takes the time of n^2 operations (in this case comparisons) to complete the algorithm. I don't see how this intuition follows from the above definition.

Comment: `Big O` notation is used for measuring both Time and Memory Complexity of algorithms.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Comp Sci sites like http://cs.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, I'm confused by what it means for g(n) to be in O(f(n)). What does in mean?

In this formulation, `O(f(n))` is a *set of functions*.  Thus `O(N)` is the set of all functions that are (in simple terms) proportional to N as N tends to infinity.

The word "in" means ... "is a member of the set".

> Why does saying that the absolute value of g(n) less than or equal f(n) for all n > N mean anything about Big O Notation?

It is **the definition**.  And besides you have neglected the `c` term in your synopsis, and that is an *important* part of the definition.

> My general intuition for what Big O Notation means is that it is a way to describe the runtime of an algorithm. For example, if bubble sort runs in O(n^2) in the worst case, this means that it takes the time of n^2 operations (in this case comparisons) to complete the algorithm. I don't see how this intuition follows from the above definition.

Your intuition is incorrect in two respects.

- Firstly, the real definition of `O(N^2)` is NOT that it takes `N^2` operations.  it is that it takes *proportional to* `N^2` operations.  That's where the `c` comes into it.
- Secondly, it is only proportional to `N^2` *for large enough values of `N`*.  Big O notation is *not* about what happens for small `N`.  It is about what happens when the problem size scales up.

Also, as a a comment notes "proportional" is not quite the right phraseology here.  It might be more correct to say "tends towards proportional" ... but in reality there isn't a simple english description of what is going on here.  The real definition is the mathematical one.

If you now reread the definition in the light of that, you should see that it fits just nicely.

---

<sup>(Note that the definitions of Big O, and related measures of complexity can also be expressed in calculus terminology; i.e. using "limits".  However, generally speaking the things we are talking about are quantized; i.e. an integer number instructions, an integer number bytes of storage, etc.  Calculus is really about functions involving real numbers.  Hence, you could argue that the formulation above is preferable.  OTOH, a real mathematician would probably see bus-sized holes in this argumentation.)</sup>

Comment: f is in O(g) does not mean f is proportional to g for large N. O describes an upper bound only. For example, merge sort is O(N log N), but is not proportional to c(N log N) unless for example you restrict N to be a power of 2.

Comment: @Anonymous - I am aware of that.  But what I am trying to do is use terms that the OP can understand *from an intuitive perspective*.  The real definition is the mathematical definition, not the sloppy English description.

Answer (score 0):

O(g(n)) looks like a function, but it is actually a set of functions. If a function f is in O(g(n)), it means that g is an asymptotic upper bound on f to within a constant factor. O(g(n)) contains all functions that are bounded from above by g(n).

More specifically, there exists a constant c and n0 such that f(n) < c * g(n) for all n > n0. This means that c * g(n) will always overtake f(n) beyond some value of n. g is asymptotically larger than f; it scales faster.

This is used in the analysis of algorithms as follows. The running time of an algorithm is impossible to specify practically. It would obviously depend on the machine on which it runs. We need a way of talking about efficiency that is unconcerned with matters of hardware. One might naively suggest counting the steps executed by the algorithm and using that as the measure of running time, but this would depend on the granularity with which the algorithm is specified and so is no good either. Instead, we concern ourselves only with how quickly the running time (this hypothetical thing T(n)) scales with the size of the input n.

Thus, we can report the running time by saying something like:

My algorithm (algo1) has a running time T(n) that is in the set O(n^2). I.e. it's bounded from above by some constant multiple of n^2.

Some alternative algorithm (algo2) might have a time complexity of O(n), which we call linear. This may or may not be better for some particular input size or on some hardware, but there is one thing we can say for certain: as n tends to infinity, algo2 will out-perform algo1.

Practically then, one should favour algorithms with better time complexities, as they will tend to run faster.

This asymptotic notation may be applied to memory usage also.